# Image trail when moving bitmap in Android

Tags: android, graphics, animation, sprite

I'm trying to program a little game for Android, and when I draw the bitmap and animate it using Sprites, I can see a trail in the image! (it's a PNG image). 
I know it is not a problem of the sprites, because I used a static image moving along the X axis and I could still see the trail

[image: trail of the animation]

This is the code I used to load the image:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

How can I eliminate it so I can only see one of the sprites every time?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to clear the background before each time you draw your sprite. Calling [drawColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawColor%28int%29) on your Canvas should do it, something like

```
    Canvas c = null;
    try {
        c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            c.draw(bmp, posX, posY, null);
        }
    } finally {
        if(c != null)
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was a very stupid thing:
instead of

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(***Color.BLACK***);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

I did a

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(***color.black***);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Thanks a lot both for the answers, because I really was not sure why all that had to be done, so both of you actually helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a `SurfaceView` or a `Canvas`?

With `SurfaceView` I believe you have to manually clear parts of the drawing that you want to disappear.